# How to calculate current RMS value for full-wave controlled rectifier in degrees?

Tags: bridge-rectifier, thyristor

I'm trying to find the clear way to calculate the current RMS value for full-wave controlled rectifier.

Should I include the pi value if the calculation is in degrees since the trigger angle is in degrees ?

I found couple examples in our theory book and an example from the web:

1. The example from our theory book:

[image: example1]

============================================================================

2. The example from the [web](https://courses.minia.edu.eg/Attach/9921Lecture04.pdf):

[image: example2]

Comment: Pi shows up several times in the examples you copied. Please clarify exactly which instance of pi you think might not be needed, and explain why you think you can ignore it. Do you know how to convert between radians and degrees?

Comment: I think it's 3.14 in the first example, because I recalculate it carefully and got the exact answer which is 14.77A. I'm not considering the pi might not needed, I actually want to know what is the usual and the correct way to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice that the voltage function after the 'ideal' full-wave rectifier is given by:

$$
\text{V}_\mathcal{R}\left(t\right):=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\space\space0\le t<\frac{\alpha}{2\pi\text{f}}\\
\\
\left|\text{V}_\text{i}\left(t\right)\right|&\text{if}\space\space\frac{\alpha}{2\pi\text{f}}\le t<\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\\
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

With \$\text{V}_\mathcal{R}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\mathcal{R}\left(t+\text{nT}\right)\$ where \$\text{T}=\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\$ is the period time and \$\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}\$, \$\alpha\$ is the trigger angle in \$\left[\text{rad}\right]\$, \$\hat{\text{u}}\$ is the ampltiude of the voltage and \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input voltage: \$\text{V}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(2\pi\text{f}t\right)\$.

So, the average and effective voltage is given by:

- Average:
  $$\overline{\text{V}}_\mathcal{R}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2\text{f}}-0}\int_0^\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\text{V}_\mathcal{R}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\pi}\cdot\left(1+\cos\left(\alpha\right)\right)\tag2$$
- Effective:
  $$\text{V}_{\mathcal{R}\space|\space\text{rms}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2\text{f}}-0}\int_0^\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\text{V}_\mathcal{R}^2\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t}=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\sqrt{\pi-\alpha+\frac{\sin\left(2\alpha\right)}{2}}\tag3$$

And the average and effective current through the resistive load is given by:

- Average:
  $$\overline{\text{I}}_\text{load}=\frac{\overline{\text{V}}_\mathcal{R}}{\text{R}}=\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}}\cdot\left(1+\cos\left(\alpha\right)\right)\tag4$$
- Effective:
  $$\text{I}_{\text{load}\space|\space\text{rms}}=\frac{\text{V}_{\mathcal{R}\space|\space\text{rms}}}{\text{R}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}}\cdot\sqrt{\pi-\alpha+\frac{\sin\left(2\alpha\right)}{2}}\tag5$$

So, we can find the power factor:

$$\text{PF}:=\frac{\text{P}}{\text{S}}=\frac{\text{V}_{\mathcal{R}\space|\space\text{rms}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{load}\space|\space\text{rms}}}{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{load}\space|\space\text{rms}}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\hat{\text{u}}}\cdot\text{V}_{\mathcal{R}\space|\space\text{rms}}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\hat{\text{u}}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\sqrt{\pi-\alpha+\frac{\sin\left(2\alpha\right)}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot\sqrt{\pi-\alpha+\frac{\sin\left(2\alpha\right)}{2}}\tag6$$